# [ArangoDB]: Get the first element of an object?

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am trying to get the first element of the object `scan`. In my case, the first element's `key` changes. So I cannot call it with the `key`. Here is the AQL query I'm using, which is not working.

```
`FOR d in collection RETURN DISTINCT Object.keys(d.out.scan)[0]`
```

Object structure:

```
{
  "out": {
       "scan":{
             "someKeyThatChanges":"someValue"
              }
        }
}
```

Is there a way to fetch the first `key` of `scan`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch just the name of the first key of `out.scan`, the following will work:

```
FOR d IN collection
  RETURN ATTRIBUTES(d.out.scan)[0]
```

For returning the mapped value for that key, please refer to the other answer given.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant AQL functions for this issue are documented at
https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/functions/document-object/

In brief, if the object has only one user-defined key, then you will
be able to use VALUES(_, true) directly.

Otherwise, you could use ATTRIBUTES() to get an array of the object's
attributes.  You may want to filter it to avoid keys with names that start with "_".  Once you've selected a key, remember:

> Attributes can also be accessed using the [] accessor

> ... the square brackets allow for expressions:

> ... u[attr1][0][attr2][ CONCAT("fir", "st") ]

### Demo

```
LET x = {
  "out": {
       "scan":{
             "someKeyThatChanges":"someValue"
              }
        }
}

LET y = x.out.scan
LET z = y[ ATTRIBUTES(y)[0] ]
RETURN z
```